# Unwrap objects in array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have an array of objects:

```
var Props = [booleanPoint, buttonPoint, checkboxPoint, datePoint, dialPoint, gaugePoint,
    groupboxPoint, htmlPoint, imagePoint, livetextPoint, livetrendsPoint, permissionsPoint,
    rangePoint, selectPoint, spectrumPoint];
```

Console log shows:
[image]

Edited:

I want to extract the properties inside each object. How do I do it?

To be clear I just want the first property in the array, so that I can do Props.booleanPoint, Props.buttonPoint etc.

Comment: So you want to add every object that is in each outer object held by the Array to a new Array? If so, use a `for` loop to iterate the Array, and a `for-in` loop inside the `for` loop to iterate each object, which you can then push to the new Array.

Comment: I don't understand the problem you're having. Props[0] gives the first object in the array, Props[1] gives the second, and so forth. Please show the code you're using with the Props array, not other code for an object that you're not using.

Comment: @nnnnnn Hi, Props[0] just returns an object that has a nested property 'booleanProps'. I want 'booleanProps' directly.

Comment: Then you say Props[0]['booleanProps']. If each object contains just one property that is a nested object and each one uses a different name you can get the name with Object.keys( Props[i])[0]. (Where i is a loop iterator if you are iterating over Props.)

Comment: @nnnnnn thanks for that, didn't know that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You question is not very clear, but I guess you're trying to extract the first (and only) property from each object in the list, whose name you don't know.

If yes, consider this:

```
extracted = Props.map(function(obj) {
    for(var p in obj)
        return obj[p];
});
```

If you want to combine all properties into one big object, try this:

```
allProps = Object.assign.apply(null, Props)
```

Comment: thanks for this answer. However it is not exact what I am looking for. I'm looking for a way to be able to do Props.booleanPoint, Props.buttonPoint etc. The method you have gets rid of the property names completely, which is not what i want.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure exactly what result you're after, but the best solution is probably either a `forEach` or a `map`.

```
var properties = {};
Props.forEach(function(object) {
    // update properties somehow based on object
});
```

or

```
var properties = Props.map(function(object) {
    return [some property of object];
});
```

The first just runs some code on each entry in the array; the second returns a new array with the results of that code.

Otherwise, the classic for loop works too:

```
var properties = {};
for (var i = 0; i < Props.length; i++ {
    // update properties somehow based on Props[i]
}
```